# "Closed, non-winning bounty" for "reward an existing answer"

Tags: discussion, bounty

I didn't receive the "bounty" for a question I've answered (before the bounty was placed on the question). I know the [bounty rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) state that in case the offerer doesn't award the bounty manually only new answers are eligable.

However I think the user wasn't aware of this and his bounty reason `"Reward existing answer"` was quite clear (there are no other answers).

Does it make sense to ask if the bounty can be manually awarded and if so whom and how? Or should I just content myself that the answer got a few additional upvotes during the bounty-time?

Comment: Maybe the bounty issuer changed their mind or just plain forgot (despite the reminders the system sends). If the bounty has expired and not been awarded then that's it I'm afraid - you'll have to content yourself with the upvotes.

Comment: It's not really conclusive but according to his profile he was last seen on January, 31th. That was the day he started the bounty. But yes, maybe he simply forgot or changed his mind. Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to come to Meta and ask a question like this, you should at least link to the answer in question so you can benefit from the Meta effect!

Comment: @CodyGray You really think so? The last time I did that I got the impression that I misused the meta-effect.

Comment: There is no such thing as "misusing" it. It is what it is: a way to call attention to something on a grand stage. If that's what you want, then you should do it. The only thing is, it's a gamble. People might agree with you, or they might disagree with you; either way, they're going to act accordingly. So, had you linked to it, they might have thought your answer wasn't good and downvoted it.

Comment: Honestly, to the extent this would be "misusing" the Meta effect, so is this question. You seem to be asking for someone to manually award you the bounty *ex post facto*, which can't happen, and I have a suspicion that you knew that. Which makes this seem more like a pointless whine (no offense intended, of course). Posting a link to the answer in question seems like a way to make it into something more constructive. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

No one is going to manually award you a bounty that the bounty holder choose not to award.

Comment: I thought so, I just hoped otherwise. Would have been nice to get a bounty. :D